# number of ways to decode a string?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am working on problem where I need to decode a string..

> A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers
>   using the following mapping:
>
> 'A' -> 1
>
> 'B' -> 2
>
> ...
>
> 'Z' -> 26
>
> Given a non-empty string containing only digits, determine the total
>   number of ways to decode it.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: "12"
>
> Output: 2
>
> Explanation: It could be decoded as "AB" (1 2) or "L" (12).
>
> Example 2:
>
> Input: "226"
>
> Output: 3
>
> Explanation: It could be decoded as "BZ" (2 26), "VF" (22 6), or "BBF" (2 2 6).

I came up with below recursion approach but it is giving wrong output for this input "227". Output should be "2" but my program is giving "3":

```
  public static int decodeWays(String data) {
    return helper(data, data.length());
  }

  private static int helper(String data, int k) {
    if (k == 0)
      return 1;
    int s = data.length() - k;
    if (data.charAt(s) == '0')
      return 0;

    int result = helper(data, k - 1);
    if (k >= 2 && Integer.parseInt(data.substring(0, 2)) <= 26) {
      result += helper(data, k - 2);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

What is wrong with my above approach?

Comment: 2,2 and 7, not 22 and 7 as you expect I assume?

Comment: I edited my question with the examples. Basically two ways for my input are: `2 2 7` and `22 7` but my program is giving me 3 as the output.

Comment: if `k` is 0, why do you return `1`? By the way, why is `k` needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line-

```
if (k >= 2 && Integer.parseInt(data.substring(0, 2)) <= 26) {
```

You always check the same 2-digit number `data.substring(0, 2)`. Instead consider something like

```
data.substring(data.length()-k, data.length()).substring(0, 2)
```

or

```
data.substring(data.length()-k, data.length()-k+2)
```

Comment: didn't quite understand.. can you explain?

Comment: `data` is always `"227"` or whatever the input may be. So `data.substring(0, 2)` always yields `22`, which is always less than `26`, hence why you are counting 3 instead of 2.

Comment: What about for instance 367? It should return 3,6 and 7 but with this code above, it will check only for 3? This should work : data.substring(data.length()-k, data.length()-k+1)

Comment: @MS90 I may have an off by one error, but even if so I know that the second index must be 2 larger than the first, since substring excludes the second index.

Comment: OK, but what about in situation like this: 1212236 -> 12 21, 2 in between is omitted in this scenario? @DillonDavis

Comment: @MS90 I don't quite understand. Could you rephrase or elaborate a bit?