# Need help understanding this dynamic programming solution

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

So the problem being asked is:

A message containing letters from A-Z is being encoded to numbers using the following mapping:

```
'A' -> 1
'B' -> 2
...
'Z' -> 26
```

Given a non-empty string containing only digits, determine the total number of ways to decode it.

Example 1:

```
Input: "12"
Output: 2
Explanation: It could be decoded as "AB" (1 2) or "L" (12).
```

Example 2:

```
Input: "226"
Output: 3
Explanation: It could be decoded as "BZ" (2 26), "VF" (22 6), or "BBF" (2 2 6).
```

I solved it very inefficiently and was looking at other solutions and saw that dynamic programming was a good method to approach this problem. Since DP is new to me, I've been reading about it and am now coming back to the solution I saw and I'm trying to understand the logic behind the bottom down approach this guy used.

```
function numDecodings(s) {
  if (s.length === 0) return 0;

  const N = s.length;
  const dp = Array(N+1).fill(0);

  dp[0] = 1;
  dp[1] = s[0] === '0' ? 0 : 1;

  for (let i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
    if (s[i-1] !== '0') {
      dp[i] += dp[i-1];
    }
    if (s[i-2] === '1' || s[i-2] === '2' && s[i-1] <= '6') {
      dp[i] += dp[i-2];
    }
  }

  return dp[N];
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you say you were looking for other solutions. I've recently [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54976434/6221024) and [reviewed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214878/counting-the-number-of-ways-to-decode-a-string/214898#214898) another variant that implements the DP solution recursively. You may find that implementation to be insightful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's straighten out some terms:

- There are "top-down" and "bottom-up" approaches.  "bottom-down" is not a useful term.
- DP is a "bottom-up" approach, in that each solution is based on smaller and later ones.

The code has a "memo" array, `dp`.  You may see the term "memoization" in your readings.  This means that when we first compute a solution to a particular sub-problem, we will make a memo of it (remember the solution), indexed by the parameters.  Thereafter, any time we need the solution, we'll simply look it up instead of recomputing it.

At each position in the string, we remember how many ways there are to code the string up to this point, and then compute how many ways total there are when we add the current character to that prefix.

Very briefly:

- If the current character is not 0, then we can count one way to continue any previous string: take this as encoding a letter a-i.  In this case, every encoding so far is still valid, so we carry forward that count: `dp[i] += dp[i-1]`.
- If the previous and current character form a legal encoding, then we can also take those as a 2-digit encoding (letters j-z), and we carry forward the count from before this 2-character code: `dp[i] += dp[i-1]`.

That's all there is to the algorithm.  Note that this does *not* handle all possible digit sequences: if the code reaches a point where there are no possible continuations, it will simply allow `dp[i]` to remain 0, and continue without issuing a message.  For instance, given the input `12000226`, the algorithm will identify three ways to encode `12`, extend that to include `at` for `120`, and then reset when it hits the next two zeroes.  It then starts over with the next `2`, and will find 3 ways to encode the remainder of the string, returning `3` as the result.